# Dynamically add a new field to a form in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to dynamically add a dropdown to a form using Ember.  I am new to Ember and don't know where to start with this.  I am thinking I need a way to render a select box after the page has already been rendered while also incorporating the new element into the model.

The flow would be something like: 1. click button, 2. a select is created, 3. select an option, 4. repeat 1 thru 3 adding as many options as necessary, 5. submit form.

[Here is a graphic of the selector generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJaHx.png)

I can't find any documentation to help with this.  Is there anyone that can help?